# Finding shadow area of a 3D object

Tags: graphics3d, computational-geometry, optics

Given a 3D object, how could one find the area of the shadow? In effect, this is a measure of optical cross section. The ultimate goal would be a table showing latitude, longitude, and, optical cross section.

An image of a sample 3D object is shown.

[image: sample 3D object]

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 6):

Here is another approach where you convert a region to a [`RegionImage`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionImage.html). Then you can use [`ImageRotate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageRotate.html) to rotate about a vector and [`Image3DProjection`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Image3DProjection.html) to project the image on a plane.

```
(* Convert Region To RegionImage *)
ri = RegionImage@ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "SpaceShuttle"}, "Region"];
(* Rotate Image Pi/2 around X *)
rirot = ImageRotate[ri, {π/2, {1, 0, 0}}];
(* Create ImageMesh of Image3DProjection *)
imfn = (ImageMesh@Binarize@Image3DProjection[#, "XY", "Max"]) &;
imfn[ri]
imfn[rirot]
(* Region Measure Should Return Area *)
RegionMeasure@%%
RegionMeasure@%%
```

[image: Output]

Comment: I'm amused and glad that the holes are retained in the first "shadow".

Comment: I guess it isn't precisely real.  You can change the `RasterSize` and get the holes to move to other thin regions.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is fundamentally *not* about a 3D object, incidentally.

Binarize the image (called `image`), then find the number of black pixels, and divide by the total number of pixels:

```
N[1 - ((1 /. 
ComponentMeasurements[a = Binarize[image], "Count"])/(Times @@ ImageDimensions[a]))]
```

(* 0.246316 *)

Comment: Great answer. Concerning the interesting comment "Your question is fundamentally not about a 3D object": Taking an object and rotating about the center in latitude and longitude implies the object is at least 3D. What criteria do you consider?

Comment: @dan, once all the necessary rotations/scalings/etc. have been applied to your 3D object, there's no need for 3D techniques anymore, as David shows.

Comment: @DavidGStork Unless your image one of those click-to-copy the code links like in the HTML documentation... I think you forgot the code ;)

Comment: Nope... the code is entirely present.  I'll revise my answer to make it explicit.

Comment: @dantopa:  Your question is about the *two*-dimensional final image... a projection of a three-dimensional object.  You you just gave the two-dimensional projection we would solve it precisely the same way.

Comment: @David G. Stork, JM: Good points. When you are stranded in 3-D and unable to create the 2-D shadow, the problem feels like a 3-D problem.  Thanks for the dual answer of how to create a 2-D shadow, and then measure it.